# PHP simple XML to array - minus character problem

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, special-characters

I have a XML file with data and run the following code:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("index.xml");
$result = $xml->xpath("product");

echo $result[0]->name . '<br />';
echo $result[0]->price . '<br />';
echo $result[0]->info-url . '<br />';
echo $result[0]->image-url . '<br />';
echo $result[0]->longdescription . '<br />';
?>
```

**Part of my XML file**

```
<product>
  <name>Test</name>
  <price>100</price>
  <info-url>http://www.test.com</info-url>
  <image-url>http://www.test.com/image.jpg</image-url>
</product>
```

**I get this error:**

"***Notice**:  Use of undefined constant url - assumed 'url' in **C:\wamp\www\concepts\xml-to-array\index.php** on line **11***"

It does not like the **minus** character. How do I get it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is to use the following:

```
$result[0]->{'image-url'}
```

and so on for all attributes with hyphens.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of xpath, I like using:

```
$url = "filename.xml";
$simple = simplexml_load_file($url);
$arr = json_decode( json_encode($simple) , 1);
```

I can then access elements by:

```
echo $arr['product']['image-url'];
```

According to comment, this is wasteful, however I would prefer to sacrifice a few kilobytes of memory / and a few microseconds in processing time for a cleaner means of navigation and significantly improved code readability. Especially when it comes to deeply nested xml files.

Comment: Encoding & decoding is waste of memory. SimpleXML library provides sufficient access to data (@Mike Lewis answer)

Comment: @Minimihi - Library provides sufficient access to the data, but the format in which it is returned is not intuitive. As such, I would prefer to sacrifice a few kilobytes of memory / and a few microseconds in processing time for a cleaner means of navigation and code readability.

Answer (score -1):

```
$arr = json_decode( json_encode($simple) , 1);
```

looks simple but generates bad array, ex.

```
<product>
  <name>Test</name>
  <price/>
</product>
```

returns "price" as empty subarray

```
[price] => Array
    (
    )
```